# Conflito entre uma chamada Jquery e um arquivo js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou com um problema em uma função usando Jquery e um arquivo que eu chamo dentro do meu html que estão dando conflito, só está funcionando um, eu tentei utilizar o jQuery.noConflict() mas aparentemente não funcionou, não sei de utilizei corretamente
segue o script e a chamada que estão conflitando:

```
<script>
var $JQuery = jQuery.noConflict()
$jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
   $(".page-scroll").click(function(event){        
    event.preventDefault();
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 1000);
    });
});
</script>  
<script src="/js/demo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que te está a dar?

Comment: O primeiro script é para rolar a página quando clicado no menu, por algum motivo ele nao executa, e quando eu retiro este arquivo demo.js, o menu funciona normalmente.
acessando o arquivo demo.js ele esta minificado, mas identifiquei que o problema esta nessa parte:

"document"in self&&("classList"in document.createElement("_")?!function(){"use strict";var e=document.createElement("_");

quando eu retiro o _ entre as aspas, o menu funciona normalmente, mas para de funcionar o plugin desta chamada :/

Comment: E não dá mensagem de erro nenhuma? Estás a carregar quantas versões de jQuery? Isso é um site Wordpress? podes juntar mais detalhes? O código de `demo.js` pode ser util ver também.

Comment: esta me dando um erro na criação do noConflict()
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $JQuery = jQuery.noConflict()
</script>
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

o site é em wordpress, e estou carregando apenas uma versão do JQuery

Comment: Tens o jQuery carregado? O que dá `console.log(jQuery);` no inicio?

Comment: Aliás! O que dá `console.log(typeof jQuery);`?

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Sergio, consegui resolver com a explicação do Oeslei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O argumento passado ao callback do método `ready` refere-se à seleção, no seu caso `document`. Ou seja, você está recebendo a variável `$` como uma referência ao `document` e não ao `jQuery`.

Provavelmente o que você quer fazer é algo parecido com os exemplos abaixo:

```
// utilizar a variável que você criou $jQuery
var $JQuery = jQuery.noConflict()
$JQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $JQuery(".page-scroll").click(function() { /* ... */ });
});

// ou remover a variável $ do escopo global e utilizar apenas como jQuery
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".page-scroll").click(function() { /* ... */ });
});

// ou OUTRA biblioteca semelhante ao jQuery que use o $
jQuery.noConflict()
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".page-scroll").click(function() { /* ... */ });
});

// ou utilizar o jQuery como $ apenas neste arquivo e não globalmente
jQuery.noConflict()
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".page-scroll").click(function() { /* ... */ });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Cara, ta dando um erro no jquery.noConflict(): 
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined, 

sabe porque está acontecendo esse erro?
voltou a funcionar mas ele esta correndo direto para a página, acho que usando o scroll nativo do wordpress, não sei se por causa deste erro nao esta pegando o deslizamento suave da página na função

Comment: encontrei o erro, estava carregando este script antes da chamada do JQuery
 muito obrigado pela ajuda